# Validation in BlackBerry 10 application

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am trying to develop one app in which I need one registration page. How should I apply validation in that for phone numbers and e-mail ? Please somebody help me

Comment: So you want to check username and password from a server or check if phone number and email are valid format?

Answer (score 2):

You can place validation in your TextFields as follows:

```
TextField {
    id: myTextField
    hintText: "Flight number"
    inputMode: TextFieldInputMode.NumbersAndPunctuation
    validator: Validator {
        mode: ValidationMode.Immediate
        errorMessage: "Please enter only numbers for this field"
        onValidate: { 
            var valNumeric = /^[0-9 -]+$/i; //Numbers, including space and minus/dash                       
            if (valNumberic.test(parent.text)) {
                state = ValidationState.Valid;
            } else {
                state = ValidationState.Invalid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can set the inputMode to something such as NumbersAndPunctuation or Email and that will affect the keyboard.  Then in the onValidate you can compare the parent.text with a regex expression or in any other way you wish.  Setting ValidationState to Invalid will show a validation error with the message you specify in errorMessage.